# EnvironmentCapable Not available Spring 3.2.3

Tags: spring, jsf

Am trying to integrate Spring 3.2.3 with JSF 2.2.1 and getting an error like `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable` The class is available in my classpath (spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar) but not sure why this error occurs.

Comment: You provided very few details. Do you use Maven or similar? Are you sure it's bringing in all the necessary jars? Have you built the .war file? Does it contain the necessary jars under `WEB-INF/lib`? Do you have duplicate jars of different versions? (you shouldn't) You didn't even provide the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Never Mind. I got it fixed. I checked all things that you have mentioned and did a remove/re-add project to server and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine when I removed the project from the server, clean/build and restarted again. Thanks.